# Angular 2 not updating browser after changes

Tags: angular

basically when I change something in my app, the console can detect the changes...

[0] 9:23:22 AM - File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

[0] 9:23:23 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.

[1] [BS] File changed: app/components/logo/logo.component.js

[1] [BS] File changed: app/components/navBar/navbar.component.js

[1] [BS] File changed: app/components/sideBar/sidebar.component.js

...

But it's no longer updating my web browser automatically (screen going white with the "Loading..." message  :( I've no idea why.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "room",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\"  ",
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w",
"lite": "lite-server",
"typings": "typings",
"postinstall": "typings install",
"build-master-sass": "node-sass -w style.scss style.css",
"build-children-sass": "node-sass -w -r app/css -o app/css",
"lint" : "tslint app/**/*.ts"
},
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
"systemjs": "0.19.22",
"es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
"es6-shim": "^0.33.4",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
"zone.js": "0.5.15",
"ng2-bootstrap": "1.0.5",
"bootstrap-material-design-icons" : "2.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^2.0.0",
"lite-server": "^2.1.0",
"typescript": "^1.8.2",
"typings": "^0.6.8"
}
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you have error message in the JavaScript console of the browser?

Comment: Have you tried restarting you application. I also had these kind of problems and restarting solved it for me.

Comment: @Mikey `have you tried turning it off and back on again`, classic! :D

Comment: Yes...I restarted the app, restarted the app as well...
@ThierryTemplier, I've some errors on my console, like "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: object is not a constructor(…)" but this is a know issue in A2 when running in Safari. In Safari this error does not occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similiar issue (beta.11) (MAC / Chrome). Following the tutorials on Angular IO, files are being detected as changed and recompiles but browser is not refreshing. I have another project (template starter) beta.8 and it is working. As soon as I find out the differences, I will give you a heads up.

update: (things that make u go hummmm)
After changing my package.json from angular2.beta.11 to (angular2.beta.8 or angular2.beta.9) I did a npm install then [npm start]- the  browser sync started and updated by browser. [CTRL-C] to stop the watch then changed my package back to angular2.beta.11 did another [NPM INSTALL] and [NPM START] 
A new browser tab opened up but when I made a change it updated the other tab I started and stopped when i launched with beta.8/9. and not the Tab it launched. It appears Browsersync is not starting with beta.11 ?

Comment: i tried same solution, and its working. but why its not working with beta 11?

Comment: Lucky you, guys ! I changed to Angular Beta 9, but the problem persists :( 
Also, I replaced the NPM for GULP and wrote the automation. I can see my gulp showing "[BS] Reloading Browsers..." that's means that the browser-sync detected changes, but it's not doing anything...

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is over one year old but this bug persists. Actually, there is an [open issue in Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1610).

In some situations, live reload fails to do its job, resulting in:

1. changes in the code doesn't trigger a new compilation
2. changes trigger a new compilation but the browser serves a stale version

In the first case, the different causes seem to be:

- a buggy version of Angular-cli ([solution:](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1610#issuecomment-277311469) switch to a different version)
- spaces or some symbols (e.g. parentheses) in the file path ([solution](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1610#issuecomment-248281271): avoid spaces and symbols)
- file system cache issue ([solution](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1610#issuecomment-278460678): use "sync" after save operation)
- too many watchers ([solution](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1610#issuecomment-259358932): increase inotify max_user_watches)
- the time period between polling for file changes ([solution](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1610#issuecomment-284587307): set a custom one with the --poll flag)

For those of you who like me experience the second problem (there is compilation but not browser update) there is not a real fix. Some people [reported](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6744#issuecomment-311047112) that disabling "safe write" (in editors without atomic saving, like VS Code, it doesn't apply) helped them but it was not my case. The good news is that it seems to happen mostly when updating interfaces definitions and [only after very small changes](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6744#issuecomment-310153570) (1-2 lines of code).

The best workaround I could find is to force a larger change (i.e. cut out all the content of the file, save, paste and save again). In most editors this can be quickly achieved using Ctrl + (A, X, S, V, S).

As last resort, in all cases, restart "ng serve" after the changes fix the problem.

Comment: Hi, David ! Well..yes, it's very old ! Before Webpack in fact. and I never had issues anymore when using angular cli

Comment: @MarcoJr Hi there!, good to know that you stop having issues. I think this bug is very environment dependant, so it doesn't affect everyone. Anyway, when I searched SO for a solution this was the closest thing I found. Also, it is reported in GH since version 1.0.0-beta.11 (same than the other answer) so, when I found this info, I thought this could be a good place to share it :) Hope it can help someone in the future.

Comment: Also, even when it seems that webpack could be the root of the bug in most situations, there are a lot of other factors. I think it is not its fault in cases when the compilation get triggered but there is not update in the browser (like happened to both of us).  Actually, Angular developers has removed the webpack tag from the issue. I will do the same and edit my answer to remove the reference to webpack, it can be confusing.